# Android widget is broken when device reboots

Tags: android, android-widget

When the device is restarted, my appWidgets are all broken. In my `WidgetProvider` class i have implemented only the `onRecieve` method, since i'm using a `ConfigureActivity` to create the widget. What method should I override on the WidgetProvider for my widget to be updted properly when the device is restarted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the device reboots, all the desktop widgets are rebuilt via the `onUpdate` method in the `WidgetProvider` class. Just implement this method to recreate your widget as shown [here](http://github.com/jera/botaoteca/blob/3127b532baf58513bc65ee4910697777f586f1a3/botaoteca/src/br/com/jera/botaoteca/widget/BotaotecaWidgetProvider.java).

Comment: This is correct, but one may also find useful to use the onRestored() function as well - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProvider.html#onRestored(android.content.Context,%20int[],%20int[])

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, register to receive the [ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142457/android-widget-is-broken-when-device-reboots) broadcast, and re-create your widget when you receive it.

Make sure you also hold the [RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED) permission.

It's best practice to make sure you respond and exit from your BOOT_COMPLETED handler as quickly as possible - spending too long responding to BOOT_COMPLETED will give a poor user impression of the platform.